# How does Vaadin work?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Can anybody explain to me how Vaadin's server side Java components work?  They seem to do a sync between server-side state with a client-side javascript engine called a "widgetset".

Does anybody have a more detailed explanation of Vaadin's internals?  I have been trying to explain it to my coworkers and am at a loss for words.

Comment: Happened to notice that you're in Calgary. I'm going to host a Vaadin meetup there in 2 weeks to go though the basics of Vaadin. Please join us if you have a chance and bring your coworkers too. https://www.meetup.com/Vaadin-Calgary/events/230478117/ (sorry for posting this here, but there's no way of sending private messages on SO as far as I can see)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically Vaadin runs your UI code on the server and uses the browser as a "thin client" (the widgetset) to create and update the DOM. All server-client communication is automated and taken care of by Vaadin. The end result in the browser is just a plain HTML5 application as far as the browser is concerned, no plugins are needed and it will work across different devices.

Going a bit deeper, each component in the framework has both a server side and a browser implementation. Both share a state that is maintained and communicated by the framework. As all communication is taken care of by the framework, it is able to optimize the transport quite a bit by only sending diffs and skip sending defaults etc. Also, since the widgetset contains the JS implementation of the browser component, no HTML templates are generated on the server and sent over, only the actual component state which is much more light weight.

Here is a more in-depth explanation from the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/introduction/intro-overview.html

Comment: I would also add to this answer that developing your own Vaadin components based on GWT helps to understand how Vaadin works

Comment: It's pretty heavy-weight for a "thin client". Basically client and server exchange state changes of the UI (Button clicked, Text changed, etc.) and the Widgetset/Client takes care of rendering it in the Browser. Therefore if you manipulte the state in the server, e.g. add a table row,  the client is informed about it with ne next request (with push instantly).